# How to submit a form via anchor using jQuery in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have something to the effect of :

```
<a href="#" >click me</a>
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('<form action="/" method="post"></form>').submit();
    return false;
  }
}
```

The expected result is that clicking the anchor will submit the form and redirect the page. This works in Chrome and Firefox. In Internet Explorer 9, the browser just follows the link to #. Any solutions?

Comment: @UmeshA It's right there. He's dynamically creating a form and submitting it.

Comment: @meagar is right, i'm building it on-the-fly

Comment: @trinth Have you tried inserting the form into a hidden element and then clicking submit?  IE might require the element to exist in the dom before it can be submitted

Comment: @kevin628 I'm fairly certain that would work but I was hoping there'd be some kind of workaround for this. The reason being that I'm trying to make a general function for POSTing from anchors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    $('a').click(function() { 
        var form = '<form action="/" method="post"></form>';
        $('body').append(form);
        $('form:last').submit();
    } );
```

Comment: Elegant solution! Wish I thought of this earlier!

Answer (score 0):

I would try appending the form to the body first. However, why do you need a form at all?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $.post("/");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I need it to be a non-AJAX POST request :(